# Error: Invalid number of parameters for "getBalance". Got 0 expected 1!

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-debugging, smart-contract-wallets

I am very new to web3. I am trying to call the method

```js
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
let nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        NFTContractBuild.abi,
        NFTContractBuild.networks[networkId].address
    );

export const getOwnBalance = async () => {
    nftContract.methods
    .getBalance()
    .call()
    .then((balance) => {
      return balance;
    });
};
```

My solidity file is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Balance {

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

And my app.js file is

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { getOwnBalance } from './Web3Client';
function App() {
    // const [minted, setMinted] = useState(false);
    const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);

    const fetchBalance = () =>  {
        getOwnBalance()
            .then((balance) => {
                setBalance(balance);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>Your balance is {balance}</p>
            <button onClick={() => fetchBalance()}>Refresh balance</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Now the problem is I am unable to get the balance in my Ethereum address by running this code. Can anyone please help me get through this? I researched everything on the internet, but couldn't find the solution.
Error says that

> Error: Invalid number of parameters for "getBalance". Got 0 expected 1!

As far as I researched the bug lies in the `nftContract.method`, but still not able to figure it out, what's that exactly which is causing the error

Comment: Are you sure `NFTContractBuild` refers to contract `Balance` ?

Comment: Yeah, 100% sure

Comment: print `contract.methods` and see `getBalance` in there if there is an input argument for this method maybe you are using the wrong abi